# Play Scala Action not receiving Multipart Form Data

Tags: jquery, scala, multipartform-data, playframework-2.4

I want to upload a file into my web server using Play Scala Framework. But the server is responding `Bad Request (400)`. I have separate client hosted in different web server.
I have made file upload action as minimul which is as follow:

```
  def upload() = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    val body = request.body
    val optFile = body.files.headOption.map(_.ref.file)

    optFile match {
      case None => Future.successful(Ok("Missing Upload File").as("text/json"))
      case Some(file) => Future.successful(Ok("uploaded").as("text/json"))
    }
  }
```

The jQuery ajax request is set as follow:

```
var frm = new FormData() ;
frm.append('file', $('#uploadfiles')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/notes/upload',
  data: frm,
  processData: false,
        method: 'post',
        crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function ( uploadStatus ) {
            alert('uploaded');
        },
        error: function ( error ) {
            alert('error');
        }
    } );
```

The update request is :

```
General
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/notes/upload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Content-Length:2148
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 07:45:02 GMT
Vary:Origin
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:511
Content-Type:multipart/form-data
Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AWqi9VT3x3VctZ0_k1V0X5PWMJB0evrZG.8ux2doySJchVgqJC9tmt%2BOBMHCN%2FD1KBOXnfhGa%2BOfM
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/home
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryhrfHwiE7FJD7GgSo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="README"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryhrfHwiE7FJD7GgSo--
```

Although, the request header is content type is `multipart/form-data`. My action is not letting upload files. Even body of action is not executed. 
Am I missing anything here or doing wrong? Any help will be of great appreciation. Thanks

Comment: Pls read that. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFileUpload

Comment: wow thanks @Haito I think I kind a did bit rush and did not read the documentation properly.